# Can I use importdata to return only a part of a text file?

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

I am using:

```
 importdata(fileName,'',headerLength)
```

To get data from a text file which is carriage return line feed delimited. The problem I have is that the files are relatively large and there are several thousand of them, which makes the data loading slow. I only want a small part of the file so I would like to know if I can use *importdata* to realise this?

Something like this:

```
 importdata(fileName,'',headerLength:dataEnd);
```

This does not work and I can't find any support for doing something like this in the *importdata* documentation.

Does anyone know of a more suitable function?

Comment: It was an error in my code, Where I had the line: MainBoardSerialPort.BaudRate := TBaudrate(9600) I was supposed to use br9600. I was a silly mistake, thanks for your time and sorry for wasting it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the lines (the row number) in each file you wish to load in,

You can use a slower, more traditional way of reading in your data. The readline.m allows you to do this:

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20026-readline-m-v3-0--jun--2009-

This allows you to read whichever line you want from your data block, but it is much slower than your normal csvread/textscan, but could be considered overall faster if you know which lines you are looking for.